# Connecting to phpmyadmin xampp mysql server over ssl

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, phpmyadmin, xampp

I was setting up a local server on my mac using xampp, however i ran into a problem when i needed to set up ssl for my site. I set up the php side to enable ssl that works fine, I can visit 'https://localhost/' fine it loads up the xampp welcome page. Now when it comes to mysql and setting it up to use ssl i cant get it to use ssl. When i go into phpmyadmin and check the variables it says that ssl isn't on and that there is no cipher specified.

I tried going into the config.inc.php and adding the following lines:

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
    $cfg['ForceSSL'] = TRUE;
```

I then restarted apache and mysql servers through xampp and that changed nothing. I then generated my own certificates put them in a folder and added the following to the same config.inc.php file:

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['ca'] = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ssl/ca-cert.pem';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['cert'] = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ssl/client-cert.pem';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['key'] = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ssl/client-key.pem';
```

That also did nothing to change mysql's ssl settings. I was just looking to connect to mysql in php using ssl. My php code looks like this below:

```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set("display_errors", "1");
   $link = mysqli_init();
   mysqli_ssl_set($link,'/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ssl/server-key.pem','/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ssl/server-cert.pem','/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ssl/ca-cert.pem',null, null);
   mysqli_real_connect($link,$dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
```

I can't connect with the code above it gives me a ssl error. Is there anyone that can help me set this up so that i can use ssl please?

Comment: are you trying to setup a phpmyadmin that connect to a local db where user access thru ssl on the fronend? if that is the case, configure you apache instead. there is nothing to do with php layer

Comment: my apache is configured to use ssl already. I want to encrypt mysql connections with ssl.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL in XAMPP is actually a MardiaDB binary version. That version does not support SSL (TSL).

Try this: [How can I change MariaDB to MySQL in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654428/how-can-i-change-mariadb-to-mysql-in-xampp)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Alright, thnx for info