# How can I change MariaDB to MySQL in XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

A. First things first:

1. Mr. Google hasn't helped me to found any reply to my question
   above
2. Yes, I have read a solution to the opposite question here
   [How to upgrade MySQL to MariaDB in XAMPP in 5 minutes on Windows](http://articlebin.michaelmilette.com/how-to-upgrade-mysql-to-mariadb-in-xampp-in-5-minutes-on-windows/)
   (and it hasn't helped me: MySQL simply doesn't start)
3. I don't expect replies like 'MariaDB is better, - stop your silly
   exercises'.

B. I am working with MySQL Workbench and because of that don't want to face any incompatibilities either now or in future.

C. Can someone share their experience (if any) in solving this problem?

Comment: operating system? version of XAMPP? version of mysql? error messages when you try and start mysql? Try and start it from the command line - you will see the error message immediately. some clues please. Ensure MariaDB is not running. Remember, we cannot see your screen. Please add the information to your question. Please don't post the answers in comments.

Comment: OS -> Windows 7 Enterprise SP1, XAMPP 5.5.30-7 (inside -> MariaDB 10.1.10), mysql-5.5.52-win32.zip (from https://dev.mysql.com), when I start mysql from console - it opens and closes immediately (so - nothing to see)

Comment: being in folder '\xampp\mysql\bin' I start 'cmd' and type 'mysqld -install' , then open 'cmd' and type 'net start MySQL' , as a result - error 1067 (the service cannot be launched)

Comment: It works. - After almost complete cleaning contents of folder ''\xampp\mysql' from remnants of MariaDB data and new unpacking of 'mysql-5.5.52-win32.zip'. - It took me to press 'Logs' button (in XAMPP control panel) and agree with creation of correspondent file (empty btw). - After this pushing 'Start' button (for MySQL) in XAMPP control panel started MySQL. - BTW, I copied to '\xampp\mysql' two files: 'mysql_uninstallservice.bat' and 'mysql_installservice.bat' ...

Comment: Just FYI: MariaDB is a fork of MySQL and compatible to it (and I don't think they'll make it incompatible).

Comment: To get to the console, "run" `cmd`.  _Then_ run `mysql...`.

Comment: Don't net start mysql -- `mysqld` (not d=daemon), not mysql needs to be a _service_.

Comment: **Did you know ?**
*Oracle hasn't been growing MySQL forthcoming, but the community wants to continue doing so, so MariaDB was created as the enhanced, independent yet mostly compatible version of MySQL. So XAMPP took on the better option too. Think before change....*

Comment: @CharlotteDunois MariaDB doesn't support some of the spatial functions that MySQL does - for example, `ST_Distance_Sphere` - and the request to add it has [gone ignored](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13467) for years. Hence I need to switch, as my project involves a lot of distance calculations.

Comment: Might be a late info, but another reason for not going for MariaDB is using MySQL Workbench.  Some of its features are not MariaDB-compatible.

Comment: Maybe you should consider WAMPServer, if you are windows users. WAMPServer install both MySQL and mariaDB. You can then use Both or turn one off. You can also install multiple versions of PHP and MySQL and mariadb and Apache and easily switch between them with a click on a menu :) **Flexibility at last**

Answer (score 80):

## Running XAMPP with MySQL

Here are exact step by step instructions for truly integrating MySQL into XAMPP on Windows. This has been successfully tested with Windows 10 and XAMPP 7.3.11 for both MySQL **8.0.18** and **5.7.28**.

- Stop MySQL (which actually is MariaDB) in the XAMPP Control Panel.
- Download the [MySQL community server](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql) as zip archive (Windows 64 bit version)
- Rename `C:\xampp\mysql` to `C:\xampp\mariadb`
- Extract the downloaded zip archive to `C:\xampp\mysql`. Make sure you extract the folder level which has the subfolders `bin`, `include`, `lib` etc.
- Copy `C:\xampp\mariadb\bin\my.ini` to `C:\xampp\mysql\bin`
- Open `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini` in an editor and comment out the line starting with `key_buffer=` in the `[mysqld]` section.
- Open a command prompt and run the following commands:

  For MySQL **8.0.18**:

  ```
  cd C:\xampp\mysql
  bin\mysqld --initialize-insecure
  start /b bin\mysqld
  bin\mysql -u root
      CREATE USER pma@localhost;
      SOURCE C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/sql/create_tables.sql;
      GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, ALTER ON phpmyadmin.* TO pma@localhost;
      ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';
      ALTER USER pma@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';
      \q
  bin\mysqladmin -u root shutdown
  ```

  For MySQL **5.7.28**:

  ```
  cd C:\xampp\mysql
  bin\mysqld --initialize-insecure --log_syslog=0
  start /b bin\mysqld --log_syslog=0
  bin\mysql -u root
      CREATE USER pma@localhost;
      SOURCE C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/sql/create_tables.sql;
      GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, ALTER ON phpmyadmin.* TO pma@localhost;
      \q
  bin\mysqladmin -u root shutdown
  ```
- Start Apache and MySQL in the XAMPP Control Panel.
- Go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin and verify that your database server is now reported as `MySQL Community Server`.

Comment: Seriously underrated. Also, for some reasons installing xampp in a driver other than your main one (usually C:) result in a LOT of problems. You may want to reinstall in your C: drive, then redo all those steps from the very begining, this worked out for me.

Comment: Note: for me XAMPP would not launch Mysql 5.7.28. The solution was to download **32-bit** MySQL instead.
Also I needed to comment `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M` in **my.ini**

Comment: Perfect!! Really helpful.

Comment: Maybe you should consider WAMPServer, if you are windows users. WAMPServer install both MySQL and mariaDB. You can then use Both or turn one off. You can also install multiple versions of PHP and MySQL and mariadb and Apache and easily switch between them with a click on a menu :) **Flexibility at last**

Comment: How do I check what version of MySQL I have? (I checked but I think it's wrong: https://i.imgur.com/rEBl7NH.png)

Comment: thanks it worked! Only one thing: the mysqld did not start so I had to replace the my.ini content file as described here: https://odan.github.io/2019/11/17/xampp-replacing-mariadb-with-mysql-8.html

Comment: follow this article for more clear instructions https://odan.github.io/2017/08/13/xampp-replacing-mariadb-with-mysql.html

Comment: Note that "command prompt" means **cmd**, **not PowerShell**. If you use PowerShell, the line `start /b bin\mysqld --log_syslog=0` will fail.

Comment: linux the great forgotten and nobody explains how to make this change for linux

Comment: These are great instructions, but how do I make sure I can use phpMyAdmin? I get a "pma@localhost is unauthorized" error.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the following way.

1. Stop MariaDB in Xampp which show as mysql running...
2. Download the installer for windows [mysql Installer](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)
3. Follow the instruction.
4. Now start Apache2 and clear cookie in your browser. Now you can see phpmyadmin and workbench showing **Server type: MySQL**

If you want to stick to **MariaDB** then you can use sqlyog also.

Hope it answer your question

Answer (score 3):

You have to do little adjustment with xampp in order to use MySQL  instead of MariaDB . I just did following and its worked , i think it may helpful to others also.

1. Download and install mysql installer.

2.stop xampp and rename the mysql folder inside the xampp directory(may be its not necessary! )

3.just start Apache only from xampp control panel . No need to start mysql.

4.Last step . Make sure your running MySQL in your system . That's it ..

Check php admin panel there you can see `Server type: MySQL` instead of MariaDB ...

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

I just upgraded XAMPP because of PHP 7. I am also using mysql workbench. I want to be as close to production as I can, but my webhoster supports only mysql. These where my reasons to switch back from mariadb to mysql

I followed these steps: (also max 5min)
https://gist.github.com/odan/c799417460470c3776ffa8adce57eece

Comment: Very easy to follow tutorial. The link has moved to to this URL:
https://odan.github.io/2017/08/13/xampp-replacing-mariadb-with-mysql.html

Be sure to scroll to the bottom of the article for the Known Issues before getting started. I ended up getting MySql V8 in which guide says is not compatible with Xampp.

Comment: The links on the linked github page doesn't exist any more.