# Connect xampp localhost from Mariadb to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, localhost, workbench

I downloaded the ff:  Mysql Workbench, Mysql Community Server and Xampp (latest).

I found out that recent xampp version is no longer using MySQL as database server  instead it uses MariaDB. Apparently, MySQL workbench is not compatible with MariaDB.

There was a suggestion in previous forum to turnoff MariaDB and turn on MySQL Server on and it will automatically connect to xampp localhost.  Which it did not, rather it shows an error message

Please advise what files needs to be configured to connect my xampp localhost and my manage server control user to mysql database server in OS X (macbook pro).

Comment: "MySQL workbench is not compatible with MariaDB" I cannot confirm this. What are your issues?

Comment: I am trying to connect  Xampp localhost to MySQL database but it would not connect.  I read in previous comment in this website, first thing to do is to turn off MariaDB server first (that came with Xampp during installation) then enable MySQL database server but no connection establish.  Error would shows up that says:

Comment: Welcome to phpMyadmin.  MySQL said:  Cannot connect invalid settings.  Connection for control user as defined in your configuration failed.  phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL serve, and the server rejected the connection.  You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.  (I am newbie in OS X)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the suggestion? This is all making very little sense. I take it you cannot produce any log outputs? Also: Can you try to connect with the `mysql` command?

Comment: This is the link you requested with regards to discussion above.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654428/how-can-i-change-mariadb-to-mysql-in-xampp..... With regards to connecting localhost with mysql database server, i have no clue how to do that especially I am very new in os x.

Answer (score 0):

I just got an answer from XAMPP developers that they build and test the XAMPP installers with bundled components and try to configure it to use external services will be error prone.