# How to configure XAMPP with pre installed MySQL?

Tags: mysql, xampp, windows-10, mariadb

I have installed XAMPP 3.2.2 which by default is packaged with MariaDB. Before installing XAMPP I already had MySQL server installed on my machine (version 5.6) now how can I use it along XAMPP 3.2.2? I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654428/how-can-i-change-mariadb-to-mysql-in-xampp) but it didn't help.

I am using windows 10.

Comment: I actually have both services working together quite nicely with MariaDB listening on port 3306 and MySQL on port 3308. As long as the ports are different and the caller know which port to ask for, there's no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop mariadb via XAMPP control panel and make sure that the service is not started on startup (services.msc). After that, make sure that mysql service is running (services.msc) - thats it.

As long as both services are listening on the same port (3306 per default) this should work.

If it doesn't, please provide any information why it won't work (screenshots, errormessages, etc.)