# MySQL error 1064 syntax but everything seems fine

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

Im using xampp control panel and from there i start the process for apache and mysql. Then i go to mysql workbench and server status seems to be ok, here is some info

```
Host: Windows-PC
Socket: C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock
Port: 3306
Version 10.1.31-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution
Compiled For: Win32(32)
Configuratin File: unknown
```

Then everytime when i try to add the foreign key for my dummy schema like:

```
 ALTER TABLE `puppies`.`animals` 
 ADD INDEX `Breed_idx` (`BreedID` ASC) VISIBLE;
 ;
 ALTER TABLE `puppies`.`animals` 
 ADD CONSTRAINT `Breed`
 FOREIGN KEY (`BreedID`)
 REFERENCES `puppies`.`breeds` (`Breed`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

I get the following error

```
 ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
 corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
 '' at line 2
 SQL Statement:
 ALTER TABLE `puppies`.`animals` 
 ADD INDEX `Breed_idx` (`BreedID` ASC) VISIBLE
```

So what can i do so that xampp will start using mysql syntax over mariaDb?

Or if im wrong in my understanding of the problem, then what should i do so that i dont have to face this kind of issues again when using xampp?

Comment: you have an extra ; after VISIBLE; for the record the syntax is identical to mysql

Comment: How exactly do you issue the above sql statements? Why do you have a blank line there (line 3)? Btw MariaDB is a MySQL fork.

Comment: im using mysql workbench and it produces those script lines for sql. I tried removing " ; " but it didn work still giving the same error, any ideas what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: is there a way to override some of the rules in xampp for sql so that i can work just fine?

Comment: If i remove VISIBLE it works just fine, so why did mysql workbench decided to add visible?

Comment: @ATechGuy You can add as many `;` as you like. Where do you have the information from, that the syntax is identical?

Comment: @DanFromGermany many places, but here is one. For 99% of common use cases mariadb is a drop in replacement for mysql. backward compatable

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120178/whats-the-difference-between-mariadb-and-mysql

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

Comment: Did you configure Workbench for MySQL 8.0, yet you are running with MariaDB?  You hit one of the differences between the two.

Comment: "Compiled for 32-bit"??  That limits you to 4GB !

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Problem is the word `VISIBLE`, remove it and it will work.
Index are visible by default.

Your question: "If i remove VISIBLE it works just fine, so why did mysql workbench decided to add visible?"

My answer: The option to mark index invisible is not yet implemented in MariaDB (afaik!).

Update:

The syntax for MariaDB is different, please see this reference: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-7317

Comment: but is there a way to make mysql workbench understand that it shouldnt add syntax that is not implemented yet?

Comment: MySQL Workbench is for MySQL, MariaDB is a different thing, although it is a drop-in replacement, it might have differences. It is not called MariaDB Workbench :-)

Comment: but thats exactly what i was thinking, is there a way to make xampp work for mysql db rather than mariaDb? Was trying to find something on the internet but non of the solutions seem to be up to date

Comment: You can try to remove MariaDB and install MySQL instead, please try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654428/how-can-i-change-mariadb-to-mysql-in-xampp

Comment: Im looking at that thread, and basically i have all implemented all the steps at the time when i posted my question. Like Mysql workbench was  installed and everything, and then through there i was trying to make a table and got the errors that i posted. So is there a more specific way to solve this issue?

Comment: I can concur. MariaDB (still) does not offer (or ignore) the VISIBLE modifier. MySQL Workbench was made for, well, MySQL and not for MariaDB. Btw. the first time you connacted to MariaDB it complained about a version mismatch. You clicked that away but in fact it is a good indicator what is going on. I know this is an old thread but it is an old issue that might (https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22199)

Answer (score 15):

Just to add to those who are using Maria DB with MySQL Workbench, you don't need to install mysql. You can just change 'Default Target MySQL Version' from Preferences to 5.7 or 5.6, and the VISIBLE keyword will be removed by workbench.
[image: MySQL Workbench Preference Changes]

Here is a link from mysql bugs
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92269

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Dropping it down to 5.7 fixed it for us. Using Mariadb 10.3

Answer (score 9):

I am using MySQL Workbench and have same problem. **Change in the Preferences but it did not work**.

**Solution**: If you export forward-engineer the model you need to change the configuration on another place.

1. Go to Model > Model Options
2. Inside the Model Options, go to MySQL
3. Then change the "Target MySQL Version" to 5.6

[image: example here]