# How to disable INVISIBLE index option in MySqlWorkbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have just installed `MySqlWorkbench` and I have found the implementation of `INVISIBLE index` which is described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-indexes.html).

I want disable this feature because the version of `MySql` which run on my server is older. So when I try to import the script I'll get an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INVISIBLE,

is possible disable it? because at the moment I need to remove manually that keyword

Comment: It doesn't take a lot of effort to find https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-indexes-tab.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54340816/2813567

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Workbench: Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'VISIBLE' at line 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785125/mysql-workbench-error-in-query-1064-syntax-error-near-visible-at-line-1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In MySQL Workbench:

Go to:

> Edit > Preferences > Modeling > MySQL.

Then, set the "Default Target MySQL Version" to **5.7**

Check the screenshot below:

[image]