# SQL Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, mariadb, create-table

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what's wrong. I created the ERD and relationships in MySQL workbench and it spit this code out. I forward engineered it to my dbms and i get this error.

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')
ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 10
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `deadiade_golfbag`.`users`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `deadiade_golfbag`.`users` (
          `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `first_name` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
          `last_name` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
          `professional` BINARY(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `professional`),
          UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 5 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Answer (score 2):

MariaDB does not support invisible indexes - unlike MySQL, which added this feature in version 8.0.

The parser of the MariaDB 10.5 seems to allow `VISIBLE` (while it fails on `INVISIBLE`), but I suspect that it basically ignores it. In earlier versions, it just fails on `VISIBLE`.

`VISIBLE` is the default setting anyway, so you can just leave that keyword apart (as well as `ASC` on the indexed column, which also is the default):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `deadiade_golfbag`.`users` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    `professional` BINARY(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `professional`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id`) 
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Note that it does not make sense to have a primary key on two columns *and* and a unique index on one of these two: the unique key is more restrictive that the primary key.

Comment: I suspect the setting is being added automatically by `mysqldump`. Do you know if there's an option to make it omit this?

Comment: @Barmar: I don't know. A quick glance at the documentation does not show an obvious option. If that's from phpmyadmin, maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434830/how-to-disable-invisible-index-option-in-mysqlworkbench?