# error 1064 mysql syntax error when I try create a Index

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench

I'm using two tables in mysql workbench 8 and run server mariadb in xaamp
When I try create a Index in a table show this message:

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `bd_dev`.`telefonecliente` 
ADD INDEX `idCliente` (`idCliente` ASC) VISIBLE;
;
```

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
> to use near '' at line 2

SQL Statement:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `bd_dev`.`telefonecliente` 
ADD INDEX `idCliente` (`idCliente` ASC) VISIBLE
```

someone know can I fix it? thank you

Comment: Going by [Alter Table - MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/) : `ALTER TABLE 'bd_dev'.'telefonecliente' 
ADD INDEX 'idCliente' ('idCliente') NOT INVISIBLE;` `VISIBLE` & `INVISIBLE` in MySQL; `MariaDB` seems to have adopted `NOT INVISIBLE` clause.

Comment: `VISIBLE` is supported in MariaDB-10.5.3 onward ([MDEV-22199](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22199))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL error 1064 syntax but everything seems fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393245/mysql-error-1064-syntax-but-everything-seems-fine)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the VISIBLE and it should work. Default is VISIBLE.

```
ALTER TABLE `bd_dev`.`telefonecliente` 
ADD INDEX `idCliente` (`idCliente` ASC) ;
```

Tested this on Mariadb 10.4.21-MariaDB.

Comment: Thank you, It work for me. Any suggestion to change mysql workbench behave to not add "visible" during "forward engineer"?