# mysql - problem with create another table with relation

Tags: mysql, table-plus

When I want in tableplus create another table with relation to table 'users', I get error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `uid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`uid`)
    REFERENCES `users` (`id`' at line 9
```

Bellow my query:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `desc` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
  `img` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `uid` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `uid_idx` (`uid` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `uid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`uid`)
    REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return? Are you using MariaDB instead of MySQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393245/mysql-error-1064-syntax-but-everything-seems-fine

Comment: @BillKarwin ok, thanks! Can you help me and convert the query for standard MySQL?

Comment: Can you please answer my earlier question? What does `SELECT VERSION();` return? Are you using MySQL or MariaDB, and which version? MySQL is not the same product as MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

edit:
-VISIBLE/INVISIBLE isn't supported until MySQL 8.0.23. You must be on an older version.
-it's failing on the keyword VISIBLE, just remove that