# Laravel Eloquent returns an empty collection on belongsToMany relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

**UPDATE:** The issue mentioned here has caused by the use of MariaDB instead of MySQL by XAMPP. I have followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654428/how-can-i-change-mariadb-to-mysql-in-xampp/58973750#58973750) to switch it to MySQL and it works like a charm.

---

This is regarding an e-commerce platform.

I have 2 data tables with 1 joining table for a many-to-many join. The idea is for Products to have many Special Offers running at any given time.

---

### Tables

**products**

```
+-------+-------------------------------+
| id    | name                          |
+-------+-------------------------------+
| 10001 | Apple iPhone 11               |
| 10002 | Samsung Galaxy S11            |
+-------+-------------------------------+
```

**special_offers**

```
+----+-------------------------------+
| id | name                          |
+----+-------------------------------+
|  1 | Awesome Offer                 |
|  2 | Year End Offer                |
+----+-------------------------------+
```

**product_special_offer**

```
+------------+------------------+----------+
| product_id | special_offer_id | discount |
+------------+------------------+----------+
| 10001      | 1                | 10.0     |
| 10002      | 2                | 12.5     |
+------------+------------------+----------+
```

---

### Models

Since the requirement is for a `many-to-many` relationship, I am using `belongToMany` method in my models.

**Product**

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function specialOffers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SpecialOffer::class)->withPivot('discount');
    }
}
```

**SpecialOffer**

```php
class SpecialOffer extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('discount');
    }
}
```

---

### Controller

The following is the controller snippet.

**ProductController**

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $product = Product::find(10001);

        dd($product->specialOffers);
    }
}
```

---

### Results

The following is what Laravel returns.

```
Collection {#610 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

The query it runs is mentioned below.

```sql
select `special_offers`.*, `product_special_offer`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id`, `product_special_offer`.`special_offer_id` as `pivot_special_offer_id`, `product_special_offer`.`discount` as `pivot_discount` from `special_offers` inner join `product_special_offer` on `special_offers`.`id` = `product_special_offer`.`special_offer_id` where `product_special_offer`.`product_id` = 10001
```

Comment: Change this `withPivot('product_id ','special_offer_id ' );`

Comment: @ZainFarooq still the same :-(

Comment: try this `$this->belongsToMany(SpecialOffer::class, 'product_special_offer');` and `$this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_special_offer');`

Comment: @ZainFarooq I tried specifying the table name before and did the same now after you mentioned. Still the same.

Comment: Are you executing the query as you defined in the post?

Comment: @ZainFarooq Just to clarify, I am not running a raw query. Instead I am using Eloquent relationships. It is done exactly as I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Kindly show how are you doing this in the controller

Comment: @ZainFarooq Controller snippet added to the post as requested.

Comment: Use the specialOffers as function. `$product->specialOffers()` this will work.

Comment: MySQL and MariaDB are interchangeable, swapping one for the other would not change anything, especially with a very basic query like the one you were running.

Comment: @miken32 I thought the same. But sadly, I have encountered the same issue the day I edited the question. It was a new model, a table and a query but the issue was the same.

So I tried the same query with the same set of data on sqlfiddle (using MySQL) and it was working fine. I switch to MySQL on XAMPP bam - working.

Answer (score 0):

This could work

```
class SpecialOffer extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_special_offer','special_offer_id','product_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a third model to the connection table, and add the two relation. And it's will work.

```
class ProductSpecialOffer extends Model
{
   public function products() {
       return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
   }

   public function specialOffers() {
       return $this->belongsTo(SpecialOffer::class);
   }
}
```