# can't go to mysql on xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

i have an issue with xampp 7.3.10 on windows10

i ran "shell" on xampp

when i tried to go to "mysql" it was going me to "marina" 
like

```
    c:\xampp
# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 8
Server version: 10.4.8-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: xampp uses mariadb and not mysql. see here how to change it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654428/how-can-i-change-mariadb-to-mysql-in-xampp

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Go through the below links

https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20151019.html

[How can I change MariaDB to MySQL in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654428/how-can-i-change-mariadb-to-mysql-in-xampp)

Answer (score -1):

XAMPP comes with `MariaDB` as default. Here's a guide on how to replace it with `MySQL`

https://odan.github.io/2017/08/13/xampp-replacing-mariadb-with-mysql.html