# MariaDB data type automatically change json to longtext even if i choose data type to json

Tags: json, mariadb

This is exactly what happened when i select  data type to json

[image: This is exactly what happened when i select data type to json]

Comment: Does this only happen with phpMyAdmin, or also when you do it in the mysql CLI?

Comment: Did not check with MySql  CLI

Comment: @Barmar yes this also happened with mysql CLI

Comment: What was the datatype before you tried to change it?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pnKWiNgJBTDR9fNwykLNAA/0

Comment: I choose json when i am craeting the table but it replace automatically by longtext

Comment: Is your database MySQL or MariaDB? MariaDB doesn't have JSON, and converts it automatically to LONGTEXT.

Comment: Thank u, yes my database is mariaDB but how can I convert it to mysql ? Bcz  need store JSON in database

Comment: They're totally different products, you need to install MySQL from scratch.

Comment: You can still store JSON in the database. It just doesn't use a special representation, it stores it as text.

Comment: Thank u. I know I can use json stringify and  json parse to store and read. But i dont want to do it. I want to store as Json and retrieve   as json

Comment: How can you tell the difference? JSON prints like strings.

Comment: [Read this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/). And there's a difference between MariaDB's [plain LONGTEXT vs Json LONGTEXT data type](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=e2feaf39e86e2888d441a53bcc5add2b)

Comment: Thank u. That means in mariaDb we can not store json as object but can store as longText .

Comment: JSON is text. SQL statements are also text. You need to make objects into JSON (text) to store them, regardless of how the db stores them.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solution: MariaDB doesn't have JSON, and converts it automatically to LONGTEXT

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=e2feaf39e86e2888d441a53bcc5add2b

So, I change mariaDb to MySQL in xamp. Now i can set Json data type

how to change: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58973750/16180226

Note: Actually I am sending request using node js APi.

here is req body: (ignore field this for testing purpouse)

Here data is the req body

Query: 'INSERT INTO table SET ?', data

```
    {
        "name": "Test",
        "description": [
            {
                "hello": "description"
            },
            {
                "hello": "description"
            },
            {
                "hello": "description"
            }
        ],
        "monthlySell": {
            "hello": "monthlySell"
        }
    }
```

}

Code to Stringify if req body key has object field:

Now i dont have to worry about stringify, it will automatically stringyfiy to store Json if a filed is object

```
    const keys = Object.keys(data);
    console.log(keys.length)
    for (let i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
    {
        if(typeof data[keys[i]]==='object')
        {
            console.log(typeof keys[i] +data[keys[i]] )
            data[keys[i]]=JSON.stringify(data[keys[i]])
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: MariaDB does have JSON but LONGTEXT is used as an alias because of differences in standards.

Comment: so, your question was really about `node-mysql`.

Comment: `node-mysql` is doing a stringify for you if it detects the column type is JSON.

Comment: Your solution is to change the database driver?

Answer (score 6):

From MariaDB website:

> **JSON is an alias for LONGTEXT** introduced for compatibility reasons
> with MySQL's JSON data type. MariaDB implements this as a LONGTEXT
> rather, as the JSON data type contradicts the SQL standard, and
> MariaDB's benchmarks indicate that performance is at least equivalent.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/

Comment: This explains the JSON type from the manual, without any context, but doesn't offer any real solution to the problem. please consider editing your comment.

Comment: There is no solution because there is no problem. Read the question and my answer few more times, think about it, then please confirm your understanding and consider upvoting my answer back.