# GORM golang create does not work, getting an mariadb error

Tags: go, mariadb

I'm trying to implement mariadb integration to my todo app, as I'm learning go. I decided to use gorm. The error I'm getting is

```
2022/10/16 21:47:49 C:/Users/xxx/go/src/go-todo-app/server/main.go:44 Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURNING `id`,`id`' at line 1

[0.000ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `todos` (`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`,`title`,`done`,`body`) VALUES ('2022-10-16 21:47:49.1','2022-10-16 21:47:49.1',NULL,'Testing',0,'Finish Tutorial') RETURNING `id`,`id`
```

For my http server im using gofiber v2.

```
    app.Post("/api/todos", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        todo := &Todo{}

        if err := c.BodyParser(todo); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        newTodo := &Todo{
            Title: todo.Title,
            Body: todo.Body,
            Done: 0,
        }
        db.Create(&newTodo) // fails here

        var todos []Todo
        db.Find(&todos)

        return c.JSON(todos)
    })
```

and my Todo struct looks like this:

```
type Todo struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID int `json:"id"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Done int `json:"done"`
    Body string `json:"body"`
}
```

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION()` return? It must be at least MariaDB 10.5.0 or later according to the documentation: [INSERT...RETURNING](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/). No version of MySQL (so far) supports this syntax.

Comment: I edited the title and the tags of this question, because the error indicates you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are two different products. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed a lot since then, and you shouldn't think of them as compatible

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly disabling the returning in your older MariaDB version will prevent the syntax error:

```
gorm.Open(mysql.New(mysql.Config{Conn: conn, DisableWithReturning: true}))
```

The gorm mysql driver shouldn't be enabling [`WithReturning`](https://github.com/go-gorm/mysql/commit/ecb6c6a014f6fa2daa89e207f3e7d75f6c4b9f91#diff-1dcceb00f9e164c3494a982e1ed69ec5fd1506d1881b9cee030e9aee740cc378R120) without a version check. This is a bug that should be reported to hem.

Comment: [bug reported - issue 93](https://github.com/go-gorm/mysql/issues/93)

Comment: Fixed with go-gorm/mysql:1.4.2+ thanks to the rapidly responding gorm developer 
@jinzhu.

Answer (score -1):

Problem resolved.
The issue was that I had MariaDb installed with Xampp for windows (PHP 7.4). In that version, RETURNING statement is not available for MariaDb. I followed this guide to install MySQL 5.7 instead of MariaDb. [How can I change MariaDB to MySQL in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654428/how-can-i-change-mariadb-to-mysql-in-xampp)

Comment: Did you read Bill Karwin's statement that "No version of MYSQL (so far) supports this syntax". Certainly not MySQL 5.7 and not [8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html).